# laravel view::share, Undefined variable

Tags: laravel

This is my source.

app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php 
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('aaa', 'abcdeade');
    }
}
```

app\Http\Controllers\Main\MainController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Main;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return $aaa;
    }
}
```

But then an error occurs.

```
"Undefined variable: aaa"
```

I do not know why this error is occurring.

Comment: The [`View::share()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) will help you to get the `$aaa` inside a view blade template and not inside controller.

Comment: ```$aaa``` can be accessed in any view. Not in controller. This will help you to understand https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: Also check for [`session`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session) if that helps to fulfil your requirement.

Comment: Use `View::share('aaa', ...)` to share 'aaa' and `View::shared('aaa')` to retrieve 'aaa'

Comment: it has to be `{{ $aaa }}`

Comment: @ Mihir Bhende I tried this, but occurred error. "Undefined variable: aaa (View: \resources\views\main\main.blade.php)"

Comment: @ Mihir Bhende While I was doing what you said, I found an error elsewhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As others stated you can share data with VIEWs. So you can access that data in your view. See [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#sharing-data-with-all-views).

You can access it like this:

```
{{ $aaa }}
```

Comment: I tried this, but occurred error.  "Undefined variable: aaa (View: \resources\views\main\main.blade.php)"

Comment: While I was doing what you said, I found an error elsewhere. Thank you.